# Standard Settings for AnyCubic Printers?

Tags: software, resin, sla, hardware

Does anyone know where I can find a list of recommended settings for different types of resin / print objects for Anycubic printers?

I realize that some of the details will need to be tweaked on a case-by-case basis, but having some general starter information (exposure times for first 6 lines + rest of the print, step settings based on type of print, etc) would certainly be better than starting "cold".

It seems like this information should be gathered somewhere, either for ALL printers, or separate ones for each type of printer.

Answer (score 1):

Times are not dependant on the *printer* but the *resin*. Please look at the resin's label, which should have recommended settings.